# Upload Image in a img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, file-upload, image

Merry Christmas to everyone.

I have 4 section each contains a empty img tag. While uploading a image it has to fit in the corresponding section.

When i click "Add image in section 1" and upload image it has to fix in Image_1 div like wise all the four. But when i insert click function in my code its not working.

Whats my mistake here.

```
<div class="pre_img" >
  <span>
     <img class="prw_img"  src="http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/REALVISTA/general/jpg/128/preview_icon.jpg" alt="your image" />
  </span> 
</div>

<input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" onChange="readURL(this);" />

<div id="Image_1">
    <button> AddImage to section 1</button>
    <img id="img_1" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" style="Border 1px solid #ccc"/>
</div>

<div id="Image_2">
    <button> AddImage to section 2</button>
    <img id="img_2" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" style="Border 1px solid #ccc"/>
</div>

<div id="Image_3">
    <button> AddImage to section 3</button>
    <img id="img_3" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" style="Border 1px solid #ccc"/>
</div>

<div id="Image_4">
    <button> AddImage to section 4</button>
    <img id="img_4" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" style="Border 1px solid #ccc"/>
</div>
```

Heres my script

```
function readURL(input) {
     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
           var reader = new FileReader();

           reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.prw_img,#img_1').attr('src', e.target.result).width(112).height(112);
                $('#img_1').css('display','inline');
           };
           reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
}
```

I have made a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/imonub/3/) for easy understanding
       I havn't added a click and tried to add that function then the entire script is not working

Comment: I just checked and it is working for section1 only

Comment: Ya i mentioned only #img_1 in my script.... I have to click the button next to it and upload the image for that section

Comment: Did you leave the form element out of the sample code above? Otherwise, you're missing a vital part of the markup...

Comment: Ya i just remove my form to simplify the code

Answer (score 1):

Give the image sections a class, or include them in a container to make the event listeners 
easier to handle

HTML:

```
  <div class="pre_img">
    <span><img class="prw_img" src=
    "http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/REALVISTA/general/jpg/128/preview_icon.jpg" alt=
    "your image"></span>
  </div>

  <form>
    <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" onchange="readURL(this);">
  </form>

  <div id="Image_1" class="imageSection"><button>AddImage to section 1</button> <img id=
  "img_1" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" style="Border 1px solid #ccc" name=
  "img_1"></div>

  <div id="Image_2" class="imageSection"><button>AddImage to section 2</button> <img id=
  "img_2" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" style="Border 1px solid #ccc" name=
  "img_2"></div>

  <div id="Image_3" class="imageSection"><button>AddImage to section 3</button> <img id=
  "img_3" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" style="Border 1px solid #ccc" name=
  "img_3"></div>

  <div id="Image_4" class="imageSection"><button>AddImage to section 4</button> <img id=
  "img_4" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" style="Border 1px solid #ccc" name=
  "img_4"></div>
```

Then use the following script to display the uploaded image to a class [in this case, the `activeImage` class], and to bind listeners to the buttons which toggles the "active" container

Js:

```
$(".imageSection button").click(function() {
    $(".imageSection img").removeClass("activeImage");
    $(this).parent().find("img").addClass("activeImage");
});
$(".imageSection:eq(0) img").addClass("activeImage");

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('.prw_img,.activeImage').attr('src', e.target.result).width(112).height(112);

            $('.activeImage').css('display', 'inline');
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/imonub/8/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try with this: http://jsbin.com/imonub/7/edit

```
var id = '1'; // set default id for first img tag


function readURL(input) {
 if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('.prw_img').attr('src', e.target.result).width(112).height(112);

        $('#img_' + id).attr('src', e.target.result).width(112).height(112);
        $('#img_' + id).css('display', 'inline');
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
 }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$('button').click(function() {
    id = $(this).html().replace('AddImage to section', '').trim();
});
});​
```